# Retrieve a FragmentManager from a non FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am attempting to retrieve the `FragmentManager` to display my `Fragment` as follows:

```
def fragmentManager = competitionSetupDialogFragment.getFragmentManager()
```

I then attempt to show it using the following:

```
competitionSetupDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, HomeScreenActivity.CompetitionDialog)
```

My `competitionSetupDialogFragment` is defined as follows:

```
class CompetitionSetupDialogFragment() extends DialogFragment {
```

However, when the show is attempted above, my `fragmentManager` variable is null.

I cannot extend a `FragmentActivity` as I am already extending a `RoboActivity` for RoboGuice dependency injection. My Android target API version is 15, so I think my approach should work. Anyone know what my problem is?

(I am attempting to develop using Scala btw)

Comment: Just try to get the fragment manager as `FragmentTransaction m_fragTrans=competitionSetupDialogFragment.getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Not sure I follow. competitionSetupDialogFragment.getFragmentManager() returns null

Comment: Why have you added the brackets in your class name ? `class CompetitionSetupDialogFragment() extends DialogFragment {` . Can't you post some code if possible ? Because in single line code its bit complicated to get your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution to this problem was to just extend from RoboFragmentActivity and all worked fine.